# How do I conditionally change the django admin form based on value in the model instance?

Tags: python, django, model, django-forms, django-admin

So I basically want to remove a field from the django admin under the condition that another field is not set.

for example, in this case:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    topic = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.title

class DocumentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Document, DocumentsAdmin)
```

I would like to only show the topic form field in the admin if the category has already been chosen and saved. I am doing this because the list of topics that should be available will be a queryset of topics that are associated with the categories that have been chosen. In order to grab the possible topic choices the category must be chosen first.

update:
I modified the solution that @alasdair suggested in the comment below and made the following modelform

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            categories = self.instance.category.all()
            if categories:
                self.fields['topic'].queryset = Topic.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
            else:
                self.fields["topic"].widget = HiddenInput()
        except:
            self.fields["topic"].widget = HiddenInput()
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = [
            'title',
            'short_description',
            'category',
            'topic',
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a model form, and deleting the `topic` field if the instance has no categories:

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            categories = self.instance.category.all()
        else:
            categories = None

        if categories:
            self.fields['topic'].queryset = self.fields['topic'].queryset.filter(category__in=categories)
        else:
            del self.fields['topic']

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = [...]
```

Then use the form in your model admin class:

```
class DocumentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DocumentForm
```

Comment: So this idea was correct, but the code you posted here did not work exactly. I adapted it and put an edit in my question.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You shouldn't need the try..except block if you check that the instance has a pk. I originally had `del self.fields['categories']` which was a mistake, but if you delete the correct field it should work, then you won't need to use the hidden widget.